# Blocked Webhook

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I have a messaging webhook setup in Twilio that does a post to a URL on a server on Azure in the format https://******.*****corps.org:441/SMS    The controller has been tested using NGrok locally and works great, in Azure when I use the get by typing in the URL I am able to get a response from the web server no problem, but the post from Twilio gets a 11200 retrieval failure.  Is there something that would block the cross domain post on IIS that I am unaware of?

'''   public class SMSController : TwilioController
{
[HttpPost]
public TwiMLResult Index(SmsRequest request)
{

```
        var response = new MessagingResponse();

        UserProfile _userProfileFrom = UserProfileService.GetByTwilioFromPhone(request.From);
```

...

```
        return TwiML(response);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()  //works fine..
    {
        return View();
    }

}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit Shoaib K. I found the problem using Postman (database connectivity error in my code). I was able to create a manual post and setting the following in the Web.config file (ASP.NET):

````
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
       <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>```
````